# How do I get rid of these bats on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was building a mob zoo and my bats got out and they fly around and annoy me. How do i remove them?

Comment: You can kill them? They're passive mobs so they won't attack you

Comment: Not sure why you're getting so much hate for this, buddy. One of my world glitched out and had thousands and thousands of passive mobs everywhere plus was lagging down to <1FPS, so I had the same question. /kill @e[type=Cow] was exactly what I needed.

PS: "protected by Community♦ Dec 14 '14 at 14:44" - this is like an Asian's nightmare.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there's a better way to do this than the ways the other answers mention, and it's **much faster**. Just run this command.

```
/kill @e[type=Bat]
```

This will kill **all** bat entities.

Comment: This only works for 1.8 (snapshots)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but if they've already gotten out, then the only way to exterminate them is to roll up your sleeves and get to work doing it the hard way.  Just whack 'em with a sword until the population's down to a somewhat less annoying level.

Comment: They  are to fast

Comment: @craftern3rdgurl They always seem to fly towards me, as they're always getting in the way when I'm battling a aggressive mob. I find just standing still aiming in the right general direction whilst swiping my sword  around, and I find they're fairly easy to take down.

Comment: `/kill @e[type=Bat]` Commands solve everything. Trust me.

Comment: I concede to you then, sir.  I'm not too familiar with cheats or commands in Minecraft since I don't use them too often.  @craftern3rdgurl If you don't mind cheating, use EpicCoder's solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a bow and arrow. When the bat lands on the ceiling and stays, you can target them and kill them from a far distance with out them noticing. If you want to TOTALLY exterminate them forever, all you need to do is type in this command:

```
/kill @e[type=Bat]
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bats) bats will spawn in areas below layer 63, with a light level of 7 or less. So, much like you would to prvent hostile mobs from spawning, light area with torches (or whatever your preferred source of light is).

To get rid of them, kill them in any conventional way (swords, arrows, splash potions, fire). They are passive and will not attack you even if you hit them.

Comment: They also despawn if far enough away from the player, so if the area has been lit up, move far enough away for the chunk to unload (100 to 200 blocks should do it), then head back and the bats will be gone, but as will other mobs that haven't been named using a name tag & anvil.

Comment: @Bryan passive mobs do not despawn.

Comment: @Mindwin "*Although the bat is a passive mob, they still despawn when going too far away, like hostile mobs, ocelots, and squid.*" it's right there in the wiki page I linked.