# Are bats considered hostile mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing on survival mode and heard a bat. I paused quickly hoping for the answer. So please answer are bats hostile mobs?

Comment: This was answered in [your previous question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177835/how-do-i-get-rid-of-these-bats-on-minecraft)

Comment: You could always find out. Trial and error is a HUGE part of gaming ;)

Comment: Please start reading the wiki, judging from most of the questions you ask, not only will it help you with answering most of your questions but it will also educate you on other things you didn't know about the game.

THE WIKI IS LOVELY PLACE, LEARN TO LOVE IT

Comment: It's a pity you can only upvote once. All these comments are so true and so valid.

Comment: Or even just Google it, most of the time you'll get led to the wiki anyway.
http://lmgtfy.com/?q=are+bats+hostile+mobs%3F

Answer (score 12):

No, bats are considered a [passive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bats) mob. They won't harm you, ever.